# EDF and basis functions in GAMs with factor-smooth interactions

Tags: interaction, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, basis-function

I am trying to use a GAM to model average daily water temperature against day and habitat type in an estuary. I have temperature logger data over 115 days across three habitat types. I am using a GAM with a factor-smooth interaction to see how habitat-level smooths differ from the global-smooth for day. Habitat is included as a random effect to allow for varying-intercepts and I also included a random effect for site (where each temperature logger was placed):

`gam(avg_temp ~ s(day, bs = "tp", m = 2) +  s(day, by = hab, bs = "tp", m = 1) +  s(hab, bs = "re" +  s(site, bs = "re")`

I am having trouble selecting the number of basis functions. When I use the default values (k = 10), this is the output I get from the summary() function:
[image: model summary with default number of basis functions]

The plots look good (i.e. represent the observed relationship), however gam.check() indicates I need to increase the number of basis functions.

So, I tried 30 knots. When I do this, the gam fits a **linear** relationship for the global smooth of day, as indicated by the edf of 1 in the summary output:
[image: model summary with 30 basis functions]

gam.check() tells me I have used a sufficient number of basis functions.

I don't know why the model does this. Logically, it does not make sense to have a linear relationship between temperature and day, as there is a clear, nonlinear trend of day across **all** habitat types when you visualize the data. Because of this, I don't know whether the first or second model specification is better.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If a linear model is assumed and a linear model is obtained that does not prove that a linear model should have been assumed. Try transformation of variables, e.g., try log, exp, reciprocals, square root, squares, and other nonlinear transforms to find what works best (goodness of fit, homoscedasticity, derivative fidelity) if the *a priori* physical model is unknown. If the physical model is known, use that.

Comment: @Carl Thanks for your help, Carl! For the second model specification with 30 knots each, I am not assuming a linear model, so was confused why the GAM estimated a linear relationship for the global smooth (when it estimated a non-linear relationship with less knots). What do you mean to use the physical model?

Comment: The basis used is the linear sum of $c_0+c_1\,s_1+c_2\,s_2+c_3\,s_3+c_4\,s_4$. That is an assumption of linearity, which may not be a spanning basis function, so using it may be more inaccurate than using the correct physics. In general, as a first approximation $P\,V=n\,R\,T$. That is the "physics" so I would assume that the logarithm of the parameters would be linearly related to temperature, and not the parameters themselves. Usually, I test rather than "assume."

Comment: Note, $P\,V=n\,R\,T$ is an ideal gas law, and would not apply to liquids. I put that in as an example of "physics," as you asked for one. Best not to assume but follow procedure; test for best transform.